# Setting up react app with typescript, eslint, prettier and tailwind stuck at Starting the development server

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, eslint, prettier

I have created a new React app with create-react-app and the typescript template.

I would like to also use `prettier`, `eslint` and `tailwind` with it. So I made the necessary configs to my understanding.

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "ancatar-web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.54",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.23",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.8",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.7.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.7.3",
    "eslint": "^8.50.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-tailwindcss": "^3.13.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "prettier-eslint": "^15.0.1"
  }
}
```

`eslintrc.json`

```
module.exports = {
    env: {
        browser: true,
        node: true,
        es2021: true,
    },
    extends: [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended",
        "plugin:tailwindcss/recommended"
    ],
    overrides: [
        {
            env: {
                node: true,
            },
            files: [".eslintrc.{js,cjs}"],
            parserOptions: {
                sourceType: "script",
            },
        },
    ],
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: "latest",
        sourceType: "module",
    },
    plugins: ["@typescript-eslint", "react", "tailwindcss"],
    rules: {},
    settings: {
        react: {
            version: "detect",
        },
        tailwindcss: {
            config: "./tailwind-config.js"
        }
    },
};
```

`.prettierrc`

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

`typescript.config`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I'm also getting strange errors in IntelliJ: `Use code style based on prettier for this project?` although it should be set or `Eslint: No results for .eslintrc.js for 20sec`. Or `Eslint: No results for tailwind.config.js for 20sec`.

I tried to google some of these errors but didn't manage to find a suitable solution. At some point the project was running but now it seems linting from intellij, prettier and eslint are fighting. Also the app doesn't start anymore.